# Get size of a pointer buffer in delphi

Tags: delphi

I want to get the size of a `WriteFile` Buffer to know how much data I must write in a buffer.
the buffer datatype is Pointer `Buffer:Pointer`, i try to use `SizeOf(Buffer)` or `SizeOf(@Buffer)`  but `SizeOf` does not return size of buffer received by 'WriteFile' , it simply return size of 'Pointer' data type (8).

what should i do ?

{Excuse me for my bad English}

Comment: What you should do is allocate the buffer yourself and therefore know how large it is.

Comment: In general, it is your responsibility to recall how much bytes you've allocated on the heap. But heap manager knows this number.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot retrieve the size of a buffer if all you have is a pointer to it. You must keep track of the buffer size independently of the pointer.

A common way to do this is to hold the size in a separate variable that you store along with the pointer. Pass the size on to any function that needs it.

Another way to do this is to use a dynamic array. The compiler and runtime keep track of the length of dynamic arrays automatically, and this can be queried using `Length`. You can get a pointer to the buffer with a simple cast:

```
var
  Buffer: TBytes; // dynamic array of byte
....
Buffer := ...; // initialize
WriteBuffer(Pointer(Buffer), Length(Buffer));
```