# Get content of a pointer buffer (ZwWriteFile) in delphi

Tags: delphi, pointers, file-io, buffer, hook

I set a global hook on `ZwWriteFile` to encryption all write files.
It's my new instance of `ZwWriteFile` :

```
function New_ZwWriteFile(FileHandle: HANDLE; Event: HANDLE;
  ApcRoutine: PIO_APC_ROUTINE; ApcContext: PVOID;
  IoStatusBlock: PIO_STATUS_BLOCK; Buffer: PVOID; Length: ULONG;
  ByteOffset: PLARGE_INTEGER; Key: PULONG): THandle; stdcall;
Begin
///
End;
```

When i call the original `ZwWriteFile` in `New_ZwWriteFile` the file was corrupted because the buffer is null !

```
function New_ZwWriteFile(FileHandle: HANDLE; Event: HANDLE;
  ApcRoutine: PIO_APC_ROUTINE; ApcContext: PVOID;
  IoStatusBlock: PIO_STATUS_BLOCK; Buffer: PVOID; Length: ULONG;
  ByteOffset: PLARGE_INTEGER; Key: PULONG): THandle; stdcall;
Begin
  result := Old_ZwWriteFile(FileHandle, Event, ApcRoutine, ApcContext,
        IoStatusBlock, Buffer, Length, ByteOffset, Key);
End;
```

I test `@Buffer` also but get same result !

```
  result := Old_ZwWriteFile(FileHandle, Event, ApcRoutine, ApcContext,
        IoStatusBlock, @Buffer, Length, ByteOffset, Key);
```

, the buffer data type is `Pointer` ,How can i retrieve the content of it and write it to file.
Any idea???

Comment: Return value is `NTSTATUS` rather than `THandle`. Why do you keep asking questions and then ignoring the answers. For instance here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24675603/get-size-of-a-pointer-buffer-in-delphi and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24798988/get-file-name-from-ishellitem-in-ifileoperation-getdisplayname

Comment: Why would `@Buffer` be correct? Trial and error is not a good policy.

Comment: FWIW, your entire project (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24220382/windows-file-copy-internals-on-the-fly-encryption) is flawed. If you change the meaning of file copy you will render the machine unusable.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I know it, but i have to prevent any copy on my system using this tool.

Comment: Who is forcing you to attempt this exercise in futility? At the very least you should have realistic expectations. No. 1, don't expect to be able to determine a buffer size when all you have is a pointer. No. 2, don't expect that all file copying routes through `IFileOperation`. No. 3, don't accept answers that are clearly wrong. I don't think I can offer you any more advice than that.

Comment: Which OS on the machine?

Comment: @MartynA Windows 8.1 x64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all we must assume that `HANDLE` is correctly defined as an alias to `THandle`. Or at least to be a type that is pointer sized. And also that the other types in the code in the question are correctly translated. If these translations are incorrect then clearly that could explain your problems.

Beyond that, the only thing wrong with the code in the question is the type of the return value. It should be `NTSTATUS` rather than `THandle`. That will have an impact on x64 because `NTSTATUS` is 32 bits wide, and `THandle` is pointer sized.

Using `@Buffer` instead of `Buffer` is a gross error. Don't do that.